# How to duplicate a document during aggregation in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Is there any way to duplicate a document during aggregation in mongo?
For example, I've got a "Person" schema that looks like that:

Person:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  fullName: string,
  matches: number
}
```

I want to make an aggregation that returns all the persons and duplicates each person's document by the number of his `matches`.

for example for this collection:

```
[{
  _id: 1,
  fullName: "John Doe",
  matches: 1
},
{
  _id: 2,
  fullName: "Bla Bla",
  matches: 2
}]
```

The result will be:

```
[{
  _id: 1,
  fullName: "John Doe",
  matches: 1
},
{
  _id: 2,
  fullName: "Bla Bla",
  matches: 2
},
{
  _id: 2,
  fullName: "Bla Bla",
  matches: 2
}]
```

I know that I can add fields to the documents during the aggregation but didn't found anything about adding documents.

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 2):

- [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to iterate loop of range, [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) start from `0` and end at `matches` number, it will return array of current root document
- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) deconstruct `matches` array
- [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) replace `matches` object to root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      matches: {
        $map: {
          input: { $range: [0, "$matches"] },
          in: "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$matches" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$matches" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RJSiuFvw_tS)